# Getting Exception in template helper: quickFormContext with aldeed:autoform

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I'm having an issue with [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) which I can't solve, nor understand what is the cause. The template:

```
<template name="staffCaseEdit">
  {{> quickForm collection=Cases id="inserNewItem" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

I use [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) and [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) to manage collections. So, I have the `Case` schema and `Cases` collection, both defined in `/lib` so they should be available on the client side, too.

Next, there's the route:

```
FlowRouter.route('/staff/case/:id', {
    triggersEnter: [
        AccountsTemplates.ensureSignedIn
    ],
    subscriptions: function (params) {
        this.register('theCase', Meteor.subscribe('theCase', params.id));
    },
    action: function (params, queryParams) {
        return BlazeLayout.render('container', {
            main: 'staffCaseEdit',
            id: params.id
        });
    }
});
```

And of course, `theCase` is published:

```
Meteor.publish('theCase', function (id) {
    return Cases.find({
        id: Number(id)
    });
});
```

In browser console, Cases are present:

```
> Cases
< Object

> Cases.find().count()
< 1
```

Which I suggest to be sufficient for the quickForm to consume the collection properly (it requires one as one of the arguments).

The problem is that, on the client side, I'm having an error

```
Exception in template helper: quickFormContext@http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?b0918af3b0bb0ae387d80c71f4230daca94cae11:6851:34
```

which I cannot trace. As a result, no form is being shown (actually, the whole DOM is left empty.

What should I look for? What could be the source of this particular problem?

Comment: Are you debugging with **Chrome**'s console? It's usually more explicit than "Exception in template helper"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit shooting in the dark here, I don't know if it will fix your problem but it will certainly help... Use this:

```
<template name="staffCaseEdit">
  {{> quickForm collection="Cases" id="inserNewItem" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

You are passing the variable `Cases` to the collection parameter instead of passing it the name of the target collection `"Cases"`

Comment: It worked!!!1 I spent insane 3 hours to fight with this problem, and the solution was in quotes. FML.