# Meteor "Exception in template helper: quickFormContext" with aldeed:autoform

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm having an issue with [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) which I can't solve, nor understand what is the cause. 
The template:

```
<template name="home">
    {{> quickForm collection="Posts" id="insertPostForm" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

The Route (iron:router) :

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: "home",
    data: function () {
        return {
            posts: Posts.find();
        };
    },
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe("allPostHeaders");
    }
});
```

And I published the "allPostHeaders" :

```
Meteor.publish("allPostHeaders", function(){
    return Posts.find({}, {
        fields: {content: 0}
    });
});
```

So in Meteor I installed `iron:router`, `aldeed:collection2` and `aldeed:autoform` and also `install` with `npm simpl-schema`.

So when I launch my app the following exception appear..

> Exception in template helper:
>   quickFormContext@http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js

I found that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496931/getting-exception-in-template-helper-quickformcontext-with-aldeedautoform) but I don't forget my quote.. so someone could help me to find what I missed?

Comment: if you comment out quickform line in html, does it work?

Comment: whitout the quickform line in the Template it works

Comment: why did you `npm install simple-schema` instead of using the [meteor package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema)?

Comment: Because the installation of aldeed:autoform specify that. I will try tomorrow with the meteor package. Thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem was due to the installation. With the autoform 6+ (the recent version of autoform) we couldn't install aldeed:collection2 but aldeed:collection2-core for installing separately simple-schema.